# Apache serving media files in SAP hybris

Tags: apache, split, devops, sap-commerce-cloud

All image and other files should be from Apache and rest of the URL from Hybris(like split load). Could someone please help me to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagram below shows how the standard Hybris Commerce content serving approach, can be replaced with content serving from Apache:

The data/media directory holding the media content data, and the _ui directory for the solution is held on an NFS share available to the Apache webserver tier, as well as the Application tier.
An additional ApacheMediaUrlStrategy is created to rewrite media content URLs based on a filesystem pattern.
Additional Directories are added with no-jk mod_jk settings are added to the Apache configuration to manage the serving of content.
[image]

to Implement this solution just need to implement custom logic for MediaURLStrategy.
Please follow the below link to customize it.
[https://cxwiki.sap.com/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=hybrisALF&title=Static+Content+Serving+from+Apache](https://cxwiki.sap.com/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=hybrisALF&title=Static%20Content%20Serving%20from%20Apache)

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/6.7.0.0/en-US/8c0f64c786691014aa95f9f6b572f248.html#mediaguide-pretty

Comment: Thanks for the help ,.... https://cxwiki.sap.com/pages/viewpage.action?Space Key=hybrisALF&title=Static+Content+Serving+from+Apache
This link is not opening

Comment: you need to login with SAP account

Comment: I have logged into SAP account , It's showing page not found

Comment: http://sukesh-kumar.blogspot.com/2017/07/webserver-based-media-serving-in-hybris.html